# Firefox won't display an image unless the web inspector is open

Tags: firefox

Firefox sometimes hasn't been displaying my website's logo image. There's nothing in the code I can find that would make this happen. From what I can tell, the image displays fine in WebKit, and displays fine when the FF web inspector is open, and displays fine after a hard reload (Ctrl+R), but sometimes won't appear after a soft reload. When I right-click on the image, or open the web inspector, the image suddenly appears, as if it had been there the whole time. What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you run a verifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried disabling all the Firefox plugins, thinking it was some extension that was causing this, but no luck. I finally got it to work as expected by completely resetting Firefox using [this guide](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).

Comment: Just clearing the cache didn't seem to work, but completely resetting Firefox did.

Answer (score 2):

i think it can be something about page resizing.

When you open the webkit your website browser window change dimension, and you see the logo.
maybe this two things are connected.

try to resize the browser window without opening the webkit.

hope this works to catch the problem.